# Update post from database

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to get my post to update just in case I make a mistake the first time around posting an article to my website.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my update code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php
$post_title = "";
$description = "";
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, description FROM htp_news WHERE id='$id'");

$post_title     = mysql_result($result,0,"title");
$description    = mysql_result($result,0,"description");

?>

    <div class="row">

<form method="post" action="update-news.php">
<input type="hidden" name="ud_id" style="width: 100%" value="<? echo "$id"; ?>">

<div class="grid_12 botspacer60">


Title: <input type="text" name="ud_title" value="<?php echo "$post_title"; ?>">
<br /><br />

News Details:<br />
<textarea id="tiny_mce" name="ud_description" rows="8"><?php echo "$description"; ?></textarea>

</div>


<div class="grid_12">

    <input type="submit" value="Update">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = '/admin'">
    </div>
</form>
</div>


</div>
```

And here is my action page:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/database.php");

$ud_id          = $_POST['ud_id'];
$ud_title       = $_POST['ud_title'];
$ud_description = $_POST['ud_description'];

// Insert record into database by executing the following query:
$query="UPDATE htp_news SET title='$ud_title', description='$ud_description' "."WHERE id='$ud_id'";

mysql_query($query);


echo "The post has been updated.<br />
<a href='edit-delete-news.php'>Update another position.</a><br />";

mysql_close();
?>
```

I appreciate any guidance on the matter.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: change "."WHERE to WHERE

Comment: I running it off xampp locally and its not giving any errors...?

Comment: I've tried all of your answers but no luck.
could this be an issue?

`$post_title     = mysql_result($result,0,"title");
$description    = mysql_result($result,0,"description");`

Before I had $i inplace of the 0's and that was giving me errors so after reading the php manual I replaced with the 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below -

```
$query="UPDATE htp_news SET title='$ud_title', description='$ud_description'  WHERE id='$ud_id'";
```

Comment: No luck...? Loading to my server to try it out.

Comment: @ prasoon Hmm Worked great on my server, why won't it work locally using xampp? Anyways thank you for the help!

Comment: For localhost you can try- $query="UPDATE htp_news SET title='".$ud_title."', description='".$ud_description."'  WHERE id=".$ud_id;

Answer (score 3):

Add a space before of `WHERE` Clause in query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need quotes in query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `description` FROM `htp_news` WHERE id='$id'");
$query="UPDATE htp_news SET `title`='".$ud_title."', `description`='".$ud_description."' "." WHERE `id`='".$ud_id."'";
```